# What is an Expr in Python AST?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working on dynamically generating code in Python.

To aid with this, I wrote a helper method which takes in a string of Python code and dumps out the AST. Here's that method:

```
# I want print treated as a function, not a statement.
import __future__
pfcf = __future__.print_function.compiler_flag

from ast import dump, PyCF_ONLY_AST

def d(s):
    print(dump(compile(s, '<String>', 'exec', pfcf|PyCF_ONLY_AST))
```

When I run this function on a simple Hello World, it spits out the following (formatted for easier reading):

```
d("print('Hello World!')")

Module(body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print',
                                       ctx=Load()),
                             args=[Str(s='Hello World!')],
                             keywords=[],
                             starargs=None,
                             kwargs=None))])
```

I was able to dynamically generate this code and run it - everything was great.

Then I tried to dynamically generate

```
print(len('Hello World!'))
```

Should be pretty easy - just another function call. Here's what my code dynamically generated:

```
Module(body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print',
                                       ctx=Load()),
                             args=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='len',
                                                             ctx=Load()),
                                                   args=[Str(s='Hello World!')],
                                                   keywords=[],
                                                   starargs=None,
                                                   kwargs=None))],
                             keywords=[],
                             starargs=None,
                             kwargs=None))])
```

Running it didn't work, though. Instead, I got this message:

```
TypeError: expected some sort of expr, but got <_ast.Expr object at 0x101812c10>
```

So I ran my helper method previously mentioned to see what it would output:

```
d("print(len('Hello World!')")

Module(body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print',
                                       ctx=Load()),
                             args=[Call(func=Name(id='len',
                                                  ctx=Load()),
                                        args=[Str(s='Hello World!')],
                                        keywords=[],
                                        starargs=None,
                                        kwargs=None)],
                             keywords=[],
                             starargs=None,
                             kwargs=None))])
```

The difference between what I'm generating (which doesn't work) and what it generates (which works), is that they passed `Call` directly to args, whereas I wrapped mine in `Expr`.

The problem is, in the very first line, I needed to wrap `Call` in an `Expr`. I'm confused - why is it sometimes necessary to wrap a `Call` in an `Expr` but not other times? `Expr` seems like it should be just an abstract base class which `Call` inherits from, but it's required at the top level right under the `Module`. Why? Is there something subtle I'm missing? What are the rules for when `Call` needs to be wrapped in an `Expr` and when it can be used directly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Expr` is not the node for an expression per se but rather an expression-statement --- that is, a statement consisting of only an expression.  This is not totally obvious because the abstract grammar uses three different identifiers `Expr`, `Expression`, and `expr`, all meaning slightly different things.

The grammar of Statement allows an Expr node as a child, but the grammar of an Expr node doesn't allow another Expr node as a child.  In other words, the `args` value you are referring to is supposed to be a list of things-that-are-expressions, not a list of `Expr` nodes.  See the documentation of [the abstract grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html), which includes:

```
stmt = FunctionDef(identifier name, arguments args, 
                            stmt* body, expr* decorator_list)
          | ClassDef(identifier name, expr* bases, stmt* body, expr* decorator_list)
          #...
          | Expr(expr value)
```

In other words, a possible statement is `Expr(blah)`, where `blah` is something matching the grammar of `expr`.  This is the only use of `Expr` in the grammar, so this is all an `Expr` can be; an `Expr` is a possible statement and nothing else.  Elsewhere in the grammar:

```
expr = BoolOp(boolop op, expr* values)
         | BinOp(expr left, operator op, expr right)
         # other stuff notably excluding Expr(...)
         | Call(expr func, expr* args, keyword* keywords,
             expr? starargs, expr? kwargs)
```

Since the `args` argument of `Call` must match `expr*`, it must be a list of things matching `expr`.  But an `Expr` node doesn't match `expr`; the `expr` grammar matches an expression, not an expression-statement.

Note that if you use the "eval" mode of `compile`, it will compile an expression, not a statement, so the `Expr` node will be absent, and the top-level `Module` node will be replaced by `Expression`:

```
>>> print(dump(compile('print("blah")', '<String>', 'eval', pfcf|PyCF_ONLY_AST)))
Expression(body=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()), args=[Str(s=u'blah')], keywords=[], starargs=None, kwargs=None))
```

You can see that the body of an `Expression` is a single expression (i.e., an `expr`), so `body` is not a list but is set directly to the `Call` node.  When you compile in "exec" mode, though, it has to create extra nodes for the module and its statements, and `Expr` is such a node.

Comment: It may or may not be worth noting, but in 3.6, the ast docs and the reference disagree a bit here. An `expression_stmt` is now a `starred_expression` rather than an `expression`, and in fact `ast.parse('*(1,2,3)')` will give you exactly that, a `Starred` directly under an `Expr`. But an `expr` only allows a `Starred` in assignment context, and in fact if you try to evaluate `*(1,2,3)` you get a special `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here` from the post-AST fixup step. So I guess they're both sort of right, but you'd expect the `ast` module to be the one that documents the AST…

Answer (score 2):

Agreeing with what @BreBarn said:

"When an expression, such as a function call, appears as a statement by itself (an expression statement), with its return value not used or stored, it is wrapped in this container."

Since you're using the result of the `len` function to `print`, it's not technically an `Expression`, in the AST sense.

See this for more info: https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nodes.html#expressions

Comment: Thanks for that link - it looks like it'll be extremely valuable on this project.