# Python: return statement inside list comprehension

Tags: python, return, list-comprehension

Is it possible to put a return statement in a list comprehension?

```
[foo.remove(i) for i in bar]
return ''.join(foo)
```

My guess is no since the code after the return statement isn't executed.

Comment: What would be the use case?

Comment: List comprehensions are meant to produce *lists*.  Don't use them for this.

Comment: Also the code after your return statement most certainly *is* executed here, so I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? It sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That is to say an issue with your proposed solution, rather your actual problem. If we can understand why you want to do this, we may be able to suggest another way to do it.

Comment: @chrisz, thanks. i'm new to python and came across list comprehensions on datacamp. what i took away was it is better to use list comprehensions were more efficient than for loops. i was wondering if i could place the return statement inside of the list comprehension. the solution as posted actually worked - i was just wondering if i could make it "better".

Comment: You can't put _any_ statement inside a comprehension, only expressions (and only a specific subset of them).

Comment: @PhillipsKruman list comprehensions are great when your desired result is a list.  Here there is no point in creating a list of `None` (which is what `foo.remove(i)` returns.  You don't even store the result.

Comment: @PhillipsKruman List comprehensions are more efficient than for loops _if you're using them to build a list_, mainly because they have a special optimization in the way they append to that list. If you're using them purely for side effects, they're generally _less_ efficient, because even a fast append is still slower than not appending at all.

Comment: Also, if you actually care about efficiency, you shouldn't be calling `remove` in the middle of a list (and especially not doing it from left to right), because you're turning this into quadratic rather than linear work.

Comment: @chrisz, thanks - there are some variables i defined earlier in the code - but i didn't think they were relevant to my question. i iterates over a list of characters.

Comment: If you convert that list of characters to a set, you could simply use `return ''.join([i for i in foo if i not in bar])`, which would be a much more efficient solution

Comment: @abarnert, thanks. i originally used `for i in bar: foo.remove(i)` , which worked fine. i saw a video on efficiency and figured i should keep that in mind even at these early stages.

Comment: @chrisz - this my first time hearing about a set in python. i'm going to read up on it now.

Comment: @PhillipsKruman A lot of people who talk about efficiency really have no idea what they're talking about. And most of the rest do understand it, but they assume everyone else understands as much as they do. So be careful about blindly picking up optimization tips from random people online. Including me and chrisz, of course, even though we're both right here. :)

Answer (score 5):

[`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt) is a statement.

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comprehension) cannot contain statements, only expressions.

In fact, that's true for *all* expressions in Python: they can only contain other expressions.

So, no, you can't put a `return` inside a list comprehension.

If you really need to mutate `foo` in-place, what you're trying to do is much better written as a `for` statement (which, being a compound statement, can of course contain other statements):

```
for i in bar: foo.remove(i)
return ''.join(foo)
```

While comprehensions *are* faster than `for` statements for building a list, that's mainly because they can use a specially-optimized version of `list.append`. If you don't actually *want* the resulting list, they're *slower*, because even a really fast `list.append` is still a lot slower than not building a list at all.

And, more importantly, using comprehensions just for side effects isn't just inefficient, it makes your code less idiomatic, and harder to understand.

Anyway, if you really need to optimize this code, you probably *shouldn't* be mutating `foo` in-place. Every time you call `foo.remove(i)`, that takes linear work to find the first occurrence of `i` and then shift the whole rest of the list up. So, if `bar` is roughly the same size as `foo`, this takes quadratic work. But you can just copy the list, filtering as you go, in linear time:

```
barset = set(bar)
return ''.join([x for x in foo if x not in barset])
```

(I'm assuming here you don't have any duplicate values in `foo` and `bar`—if you do, I'd be willing to bet `remove` wasn't actually doing what you want. But, if so, you do need something a bit more complicated here.)

Comment: Well, they can contain expression statements :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sure, without context an expression statement in the code is indistinguishable from an expression (or I think a splat-expression in current versions?) in the code, but they are different node types in the grammar (and the actual parser), and in context the grammar can never produce an expression statement node inside a comprehension.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Of course looked at another way, _semantically_ they certainly do contain statements, and even a return statement, because of the way their behavior is defined (and implemented by the CPython compiler)… :)

Comment: That was meant more as a quip, but your response lead me to this good question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429034/what-is-an-expr-in-python-ast?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, I know you weren't serious… but meanwhile, after reading: [The Abstract Grammar section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar) says an `Expr` contains an `expr`, but the [Simple Statements reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) says an `expression_stmt` contains a `starred_expression`. It looks the reference is right in that you can _parse_ `*(1,2,3)` as an expression—but the `ast` module is right in that a post-processing step raises a special `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here`

Comment: @abarnert foo is a list of all elements and bar is sublist of foo, so there are duplicates. initially, foo was a string instead of list, so i converted to a list to be able to change its elements.  i was able to remove the elements in foo that were also in bar using the two methods i mentioned earlier: the list comprehension and for loop.